# Bootsfaces handle mousedown/mouseup on mobile

Tags: jquery, jsf, bootsfaces

There is a way to handle touch events with bootsfaces ?

For instance, does onmouseup or onmousedown or even onclick on mobile when the user touch the element ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've planned touch support for the next version of BootsFaces (0.9.0). But even today, touching an element is treated like a mouse click. What we don't support yet are typical mobile actions like `<b:shake />`, `<b:pinch />`, multitouch and using the gyroscope.